# Why am I getting this React EmailJS Error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, npm, node-modules

I used the install command for emailjs

```
npm install --save @emailjs/browser
```

and it was successfully installed. it did say in the terminal

```
71 vulnerabilities (13 low, 19 moderate, 36 high, 3 critical)
```

I am trying to import emailjs with the line

```
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
```

with no reference to it and I geet the following error:

```
./node_modules/@emailjs/browser/es/models/EmailJSResponseStatus.js 4:29
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:29)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export var EmailJSResponseStatus = function EmailJSResponseStatus(httpResponse) {
|   _classCallCheck(this, EmailJSResponseStatus);
>   this.status = httpResponse?.status || 0;
|   this.text = httpResponse?.responseText || 'Network Error';
| };
```

I tried changin the file EmailJSResponseStatus.js to what it shows as it currently is this:

```
export class EmailJSResponseStatus {
    constructor(httpResponse) {
        this.status = httpResponse?.status || 0;
        this.text = httpResponse?.responseText || 'Network Error';
    }
}
```

which did not work. I also tried installing different versions, I don't understand what's wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

If there are recommendations to go about getting emails setup from a contact form instead of this using reactjs I would also appreciate that assuming I won't be getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

enter the node_modules folder of your project, look for the @emailjs/browser folder > es > models > EmailJSResponseStatus.js , comment all the code and copy

```
   export class EmailJSResponseStatus {
        constructor(httpResponse) {
            this.status = httpResponse.status;
            this.text = httpResponse.responseText;
        }
    }
```

that fix it